# Add delimiter when writing a txt file

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

I need help to add a `"|"` delimiter when I write a `.txt` file in my C program.

```
typedef struct aluno {
  char nome[100];
  int idade;
  int nota;
}tAluno; 

  void escreve (char *nomeArquivo) {
  tAluno aluno;
  FILE *arq = fopen(nomeArquivo, "w");
    
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i ++) {
    printf("Nome: ");
    scanf("%s", aluno.nome);
    printf("Idade: ");
    scanf("%d,", &aluno.idade);
    printf("Nota: ");
    scanf("%d,", &aluno.nota);

    fprintf(arq, "%s", aluno.nome);
    fprintf(arq, "%d", aluno.idade);
    fprintf(arq, "%d", aluno.nota);
  }
}
```

Without the demiliter my file would look somthing like this:

```
claudio2510natalia2518
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
claudio|25|10|natalia|10|18
```

Comment: And what's preventing you from just adding that into your format string in the `fprintf` calls?

Comment: Don't you want a new line separating Claudio's information from Natalia’s?

Answer (score 1):

You should simply add some code to output delimiters. Be careful not to add delimiters before the first element nor after the last element.

```c
    if (i > 0) fprintf(arq, "|");
    fprintf(arq, "%s|", aluno.nome);
    fprintf(arq, "%d|", aluno.idade);
    fprintf(arq, "%d", aluno.nota);
```

Comment: or maybe just `fprintf(arq, "%s|%d|%d", aluno.nome, aluno.idade. aluno.nota);`

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `|` to the printf and fprintf functions
The %s is only used by printf to determine where to put the first string argument.

```
fprintf(arq, "%s | ", var);
printf("%s |", var);
```